# Is there some dart library to read and write pubspecs?

Tags: dart

I'm searching for a dart library that is able to read and write pubspecs.

I saw that the pub package (https://github.com/dart-lang/pub) has a pubspec class, but I couldn't find pub on pub ironically.

Any other packages on pub that could do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [yaml](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yaml) for raw access, [den_api](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/den_api) or [pubspec](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pubspec) for more specialized support.

Answer (score 2):

Pubspecs are written in [YAML](http://yaml.org/) (YAML Ain't Markup Language) and therefore you should've been looking for YAML Parsers in Dart. Fortunately, there's a simple and straightforward library that you can use: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yaml